How do I use data from one data frame to search and obtain first occurrence in another dataset?
I have two data frames. One is a group of variables and a number representing the average. I have another data frame that has a list of values over time for each of the variables. I want to search for the first occurrence of the average from the first data frame for each variable in the second data frame.
Here's a simplified example:
df1:



Variable
Mean




1
5


2
6


3
7



df2:



Variable
Year
Value




1
2000
1


2
2000
3


3
2000
7


1
2001
4


2
2001
6


3
2001
9


1
2002
1


2
2002
7


3
2002
10


1
2003
4



I would like to obtain:

the year of first occurrence of  the mean or greater for each variable.
if the value has not occurred yet I would like a statement that says it hasn't not occurred

In order to get the first date of occurrence I tried:
newdataset<- df2[which(df2$Variable==df1$Variable & df2$Value>=df1$Mean,arr.ind = TRUE)[1],]

I got the following error:
longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

I am assuming this is due to the fact that one dataset is 1 occurrence of each variable and the other is multiple and I need to loop through the second list for each variable somehow.
So then I tried:
newdataset<- df2[which(df2$Variable%in%df1$Variable & df2$Value>=df1$Mean,arr.ind = TRUE)[1],]

and this solved one of the errors but I am not sure how to make the >= operator searchable in the second dataset.
I have also looked in the the dplyr filter option but I don't think it will work because it will return all the rows in the column that match not just the first one.
Any ideas?

It sounds like you want to join the data frames, filter to rows where Value >= Mean, group by Variable, then summarise the minimum year remaining for each Variable. There are lots of ways to do this, but as you mention dplyr, here is one:
df2 |>
    inner_join(df1, by = "Variable") |>
    # make Variable a factor so we can keep groups with no Variable >= mean
    mutate(Variable = factor(Variable)) |>
    filter(Value >= Mean) |>
    # do not drop groups with no observations
    group_by(Variable, .drop = FALSE) |>
    # if length(Year)==0, there were no obs, so return NA
    summarise(Year = ifelse(length(Year) == 0, NA, min(Year)))
#   Variable Year
# 1        1   NA
# 2        2 2001
# 3        3 2000

base R approach
Alternatively, if you want to stick to base R, you could do the join and then bind this to any missing rows:

first_mean <- df2 |>
    merge(df1, by = "Variable") |>
    subset(Value >= Mean) |>
    aggregate(Year ~ Variable, data = _, FUN = min)
#   Variable Year
# 1        2 2002
# 2        3 2001

data.frame(
    Variable = setdiff(df1$Variable, first_mean$Variable),
    Year = NA_integer_
) |> rbind(first_mean)
#   Variable Year
# 1        1   NA
# 2        2 2001
# 3        3 2000

Data
df1 <- data.frame(Variable = c(1, 2, 3), Mean = c(5, 6, 7))
df2 <- data.frame(
    Variable = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1),
    Year = c(2000, 2000, 2000, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2003),
    Value = c(1, 3, 7, 4, 6, 9, 1, 7, 10, 4)
)


You could subset and throw a message or a warning or use stop for an error, depending how serious you want to define the case; I'll use warning.
> lapply(df1$Variable, \(x) {
+   o <- subset(df2, Variable == x & Value >= df1$Mean[df1$Variable == x]) |> 
+     head(1)
+   if (!NROW(o)) warning(sprintf('%s has not occured yet', sQuote(x)), call.=FALSE)
+   o
+ }) |> do.call(what='rbind')
  Variable Year Value
5        2 2001     6
3        3 2000     7
Warning message:
‘1’ has not occured yet 

If we can't assume the data are as nicely sorted as in your toy data, you may implement it in the function, e.g. using sort_by() before head().

library(tibble)
library(dplyr)

df1 <- tribble(
  ~Variable,    ~Mean,
  1,    5,
  2,    6,
  3,    7
)

df2 <- tribble(
  ~Variable,    ~Year,  ~Value,
  1,    2000,   1,
  2,    2000,   3,
  3,    2000,   7,
  1,    2001,   4,
  2,    2001,   6,
  3,    2001,   9,
  1,    2002,   1,
  2,    2002,   7,
  3,    2002,   10,
  1,    2003,   4
)

res <- left_join(df2, df1) |> 
  filter(Value >= Mean) |> # Filter out cases where the value is greater or equal to the mean
  filter(Year == min(Year), .by = Variable) # Further draw down to the first instance

# the year of first occurrence of the mean or greater for each variable.
res
#> # A tibble: 2 × 4
#>   Variable  Year Value  Mean
#>      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1        3  2000     7     7
#> 2        2  2001     6     6

# if the value has not occurred yet I would like a statement that says it hasn't not occurred
anti_join(df2, res, by = "Variable")
#> # A tibble: 4 × 3
#>   Variable  Year Value
#>      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1        1  2000     1
#> 2        1  2001     4
#> 3        1  2002     1
#> 4        1  2003     4

